# Find average of time in (hh mm ss) format in java

Tags: java

I want to Calculate the average of three time in hh:mm:ss format .  I tried the following code .

```
public String calculateAverageOfTime() 
{
    String timeInHHmmss = "08:00:00 08:00:00 08:00:00";
    String[] split = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");
    long hh = 0,mm = 0,ss = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        String[] split1 = split[i].split(":");            
        hh += Long.valueOf(split1[0].trim());
        mm += Long.valueOf(split1[1].trim()); 
        ss += Long.valueOf(split1[2].trim());
    }
    hh = hh / split.length ;
    mm = mm / split.length ;
    ss = ss / split.length ;
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh,mm,ss);       
    return hms;
}
```

This code works well. Is there any efficient way to do this ? . Any method available in Java API .

Comment: You would lose precision with integer division, so basicly it can give you a faulty average. Better way would be convert times to seconds then divide to length and convert back to hour notation.

Comment: This code does NOT work well.  It gives the correct answer one time in nine if there are three times.  In general, it gives the correct answer one time in n^2 if n is the number of times.  Did you test it at all?

Comment: The `LocalTime` class of java.time (the modern Java date and time API) will be of great help here. One option is to convert to nanosecond of day (there’s a method for that), calculate the average and convert back.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is not correct, try for example with input `08:00:00 08:00:00 09:30:00`. As @StephenC said it, you cannot average times by averaging hour, minute, second components. Times are like base-60 numbers, you know, 60 seconds + 1 = 1:00 instead of 61.

This is correct, calculating the sum of seconds, then taking average and converting back to time:

```
public static String calculateAverageOfTime(String timeInHHmmss) {
    String[] split = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");
    long seconds = 0;
    for (String timestr : split) {
        String[] hhmmss = timestr.split(":");
        seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[0]) * 60 * 60;
        seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[1]) * 60;
        seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[2]);
    }
    seconds /= split.length;
    long hh = seconds / 60 / 60;
    long mm = (seconds / 60) % 60;
    long ss = seconds % 60;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh,mm,ss);
}
```

Using `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` or `Joda` would make the code easier to understand, but I don't think it can be more efficient than this, as this code does strictly what you want to do, which is averaging a base-60 number.

As others have pointed out, beware of the precision loss when averaging.

You might also want to validate that the input string is in the correct format, otherwise the algorithm will break.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single method in the Java API that will solve this problem.  But there are some that will help.

What you need to do is to break the problem down into parts:

- Convert time strings to numbers.
- Average the numbers
- Convert the average back to a time string.

The problems of converting a time string to a number and a number to a time string can be solved using the `SimpleDateFormat` class, or the 3rd-party Joda time class library.  Or you could manually extract the hours/minutes/seconds component, convert each to an integer and then *compute* the number of seconds.

The problem of averaging 3 numbers can be solved with one line of Java ... though you need to beware of the fact that integer division *truncates* the result.

---

For the record, you *cannot* average 3 times by averaging their three components, as you current code tries to do.  It doesn't make mathematical sense.

Comment: I believe your assumption of getting average of components is slightly mistaken. If you don't lose precision while taking averages of components it works. That's basically how BigInteger math works undercover.

Comment: @frail - You can't make that assumption (that you don't lose precision) which is why it makes no mathematical sense.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
        String timeInHHmmss = "08:00:00 08:00:00 08:00:00";
        String[] split = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");
        long sum = 0L;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
            {
                sum += sdf.parse(split[i]).getTime(); 
            }
        Date avgDate = new Date((sum/split.length));
        System.out.println("avg Date is:"+sdf.format(avgDate));
```

Convert to java.util.Date and then you can do all kinds of operations.

Check [Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: Great work (NOT!).  Now he doesn't need to *learn* how to do it himself.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers