# calculate average of time(hh:mm:ss) of a 24 hour clock

Tags: java

I have time in HHMMSS 23:00:00, 1:00:00. So the average of time should be 00:00:00. I am doing this in Java. But I can't get the logic

I have gone to this link
'[Find average of time in (hh mm ss) format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331306/find-average-of-time-in-hh-mm-ss-format-in-java)'
which showed multiply by 60, but this will not work if the time is after 23:00:00 and 1:00:00.

```
public static String calculateAverageOfTime(String timeInHHmmss) {
String[] split = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");
long seconds = 0;
for (String timestr : split) {
    String[] hhmmss = timestr.split(":");
    seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[0]) * 60 * 60;
    seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[1]) * 60;
    seconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[2]);
}
seconds /= split.length;
long hh = seconds / 60 / 60;
long mm = (seconds / 60) % 60;
long ss = seconds % 60;
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh,mm,ss);}
```

Comment: Avregae of 23:00:00, 1:00:00 could as well as 12:00:00 ... Because (23+1)/2 = 12

Comment: The scenario is not really deterministic: it depends on whether you're looking at it as 23:00 to 01:00 or 01:00 to 23:00. Maybe it would depend on the order in which the values are passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution that uses `LocalTime` and `Duration`

```
static LocalTime stringToTime(String str) {
    String[] components = str.split(":");
    return  LocalTime.of( Integer.valueOf(components[0]), Integer.valueOf(components[1]), Integer.valueOf(components[2]));
}

public static String calculateAverageOfTime(String timeInHHmmss) {
  String[] timesArray = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");

  LocalTime startTime = stringToTime(timesArray[0]);
  LocalTime endTime = stringToTime(timesArray[1]);

  Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
  if (startTime.isAfter(endTime)) {
    duration = duration.plusHours(24);
  }

  LocalTime average = startTime.plus(duration.dividedBy(2L));
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

  return average.format(dtf);
}
```

Error handling is non existent so I assume the input string contains two correctly formatted time values

Answer (score 2):

Considering the time is in the chronological order, so in "23:00:00 1:00:00" 1:00:00 means 1 am of the next day, you can use the following calculateAverageOfTime method variation

```
public static String calculateAverageOfTime(String timeInHHmmss) {
String[] split = timeInHHmmss.split(" ");
long seconds = 0;
long lastSeconds = 0;

for (String timestr : split) {
    String[] hhmmss = timestr.split(":");
    long currentSeconds = 0;

    currentSeconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[0]) * 60 * 60;
    currentSeconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[1]) * 60;
    currentSeconds += Integer.valueOf(hhmmss[2]);

    if (currentSeconds < lastSeconds)
        currentSeconds += 24 * 60 * 60; //next day
    seconds += currentSeconds;
    lastSeconds = currentSeconds;

}
seconds /= split.length;

long hh = (seconds / 60 / 60) % 24;
long mm = (seconds / 60) % 60;
long ss = seconds % 60;
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh,mm,ss);}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler implementation would look like this:

```
LocalDateTime min = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(23).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
LocalDateTime max = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).withHour(1).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
LocalDateTime avg = min.plus(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(min, max)/2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

Example:

```
LocalDateTime min = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(20).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
LocalDateTime max = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(22).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
LocalDateTime avg = min.plus(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(min, max)/2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
System.out.println(avg);
```

Output:

```
2019-05-24T20:00
2019-05-24T22:00
2019-05-24T21:00
```

Comment: And how would this work with any other values? What if the times are "20:00:00" and "22:00:00"?

Comment: Yes of course it works when you adjust the code like that. What I meant, and sorry for not being very clear, is that your answer is incomplete in that it doesn't handle different combinations of input.

Comment: All you need is a LocalDateTime object. You can construct it however you want based on the inputs you have.